# Проблема с библиотекой recyclerview­v7

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gradle, библиотеки

Добавил в Gradle библиотеку `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`, 
создал xml файл с кодом:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crime_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Создал фрагмент:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

 public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__crime_list, container,
                false);
        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
                (getActivity()));
        return view;
    }
}
```

После запуска появилась ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.semenov.criminalintent"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так и как это исправить

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, импорты фрагмента и проверьте, нет ли в Gradle другой версии RecyclerView

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, импорты в вопрос добавил, других версий RecyclerView в Gradle нет (на всякий случай я добавил в вопрос код Gradle тоже)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужна другая версия RecyclerView

Используйте в Xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Вместо

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

И уберите из Gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Вы уже используете androidx , ориентируйтесь на него

И, как я понял, Вы ориентируетесь на какую-то книгу, заменяйте все указанные в ней зависимости на androidx

Comment: Спасибо большое! (ориентируюсь на книгу Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 3-е издание)